# The same xpath yields different extraction results from the same webpage

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-crawler, lxml

I am crawling this website, [https://www.ntuh.gov.tw/labmed/檢驗目錄/Lists/2015/BC.aspx](https://www.ntuh.gov.tw/labmed/%E6%AA%A2%E9%A9%97%E7%9B%AE%E9%8C%84/Lists/2015/BC.aspx). It is an aspx so I plan to use `selenium` to get multiple pages of the table in the same url. However, I cannot extract the table even though I believe I am using the correct xpath.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from lxml import etree, html

url = "https://www.ntuh.gov.tw/labmed/檢驗目錄/Lists/2015/BC.aspx"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
# The url is visited with Chrome correctly
root = etree.fromstring(browser.page_source, etree.HTMLParser())
root.xpath("//table[@class='ms-listviewtable']/tr")
# It gives me [] while browser.page_source is a string of html
```

Still, I can use the very same xpath to get (part of the) data successfully - except that only the information on the first page of the table can be crawled, which is undesirable.

```
result = ""
while result == "":
    try:
        # Certificate is not verified to bypass the SSLError
        # Not secure though
        result = requests.get(url, verify = False)
        break
    except:
        sleep(5)
        continue
# Transform it into an element tree
root = etree.fromstring(result.content, etree.HTMLParser())
# Parse the information with Xpath
root.xpath("//table[@class='ms-listviewtable']/tr")
# It gives me many elements of tr tags
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Result is obviously paginated, an Ajax call is made to get the next page.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I am aware of that and that's way I am trying using `selenium` since it can "click" on the webpage for me. Still the empty list doesn't make sense for me because it should at least get the data from the first page of the result, like I mentioned in the post above.

Comment: Try to get the result in static form, save the html and use xmllint or another tool to test/debug xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully run the following in browser to retrieve the table on first and second page

`$x("//table[@class='ms-listviewtable']//tr")`

The only difference is I have the double `//tr` versus your single `/tr`

The single `/` fails because `tr` is not a direct child of `table` element

You can read up on Xpath here: https://devhints.io/xpath